# Identifying coefficients to determine cutting speed for PA6 plastic

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining, plastic

As part of a study at work, I have to calculate the cutting speed and feed rates for cutting plastic.

I have found a formula for cutting speed calculation:

$$v={{C_V*K}\over{T^m+t^{x_v}+s^{y_v}}}$$

where:

- $C_V$ is a coefficient that is dependent on processing conditions;
- $m$ is the specific retention figure;
- $x_v,\ y_v$ are coefficients relative to the cutting depth and feed;
- $K$ is a correction coefficient;
- $T$ is sharpness resistance; and
- $s$ is the feed rate.

<sub>*variable descriptions may not be completely correct as they were translated from Russian*</sub>

For cutting metal there are lots of tables and sources for finding the coefficients but I can't find any for cutting plastic.

How can I calculate the cutting speed for plastic? Is there a different formula that doesn't involve these coefficients, or another method I can use to identify the coefficients?